# How to encrypt django username field in auth model?

Tags: django, encryption

I want to encrypt the username data before save in django auth User model, and decrypt the username data. we are using model like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile_data',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Regarding this Any solution reference pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `save` method, and do the encryption logic in there. It would be executed just before saving anything in `Profile Modal`. Like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile_data',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def encrypt(self, to_be_encrypted_value):
        # Here, you would do the logic of encrypting, and return the encrypted value.
        # To be used in save method.
        ...
        return encrypted_value

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.encrypt(self.user)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```